# Pulley problem: not sure if my answer is correct

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, textbook-erratum

Two blocks of mass are connected by a massless string that runs of a pulley as shown. If there is no friction between m1 and the table, find the tension in the string.

[image: picture of the problem]
**According to the answer key, the answer is 7.0 N.** But that doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Consider the force acting on m2:

F_m2 = m2*a2 = m2 * gravity - F_tension.

F_tension = m2 * gravity - m2 * a2

We know that F_tension = m_1 * a_1 and also that a_1 = a_2.

F_tension = a * m1

**= m1 * (m2*g)/(m1 + m2) ~ 39 N.**

Again, sorry if this problem seems to trivial. I'd just like to know if my thinking is correct.

Comment: Checked this, I get the same answer as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the answers mentioned, if you have applied the correct equations.

Lets take tension as T.
As m1 is laying on a friction-less plane, it's force of acceleration = T

and acceleration a is same for both the masses,  as they move as  a system and not independently.

So, all we get is

T= m1*a

and

m2*a = m2*g -T

replacing T we get

m2*a = m2*g - m1*a

From the 2 equations above,

T = m1*m2*g/(m1+m2)

So, your assessment of the problem is correct.

Comment: Okay, thank goodness. I thought I was going crazy. So the answer key is wrong.

Comment: You are correct. Yes, somethings the key answers are wrong. If your approach is right, nothing can stop you.